# Entity framework, DataGridView: InvalidOperationException when adding an item

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, entity-framework-6

I can't get rid of an exception that I'm getting when adding an item to a `DataGridView` with the `AllowUserToAddRows` set to `true`. I already figured out this all is happening because there's a row focused and ready to be filled in (so setting the property to `false` or disabling the grid fixes the problem), but I'm still wondering: **Is it a bug or an expected behavior and I'm doing it wrong?**

Example code (a `Button` and a `DataGridView` on a `Form`):

```
namespace test
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public class Entity
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }

        BindingList<Entity> list = new ObservableCollection<Entity>().ToBindingList();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataView.DataSource = list;
        }

        private void clickMeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            list.Add(new Entity
            {
                Text = "Hello"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Clicking the button causes the InvalidOperationException to be thrown.

Comment: your code works fine for me ... maybe it's because if have entity framework 6.1.0 installed?

Comment: Okay, it was a bug in Visual Studio. I updated to 2013 Update 2 and the problem seems to be gone.